# Do I need to restart my server after editing fstab and mtab?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, fstab, awstats

I'm just wondering if I need to restart my server after editing fstab and mtab. I changed something in this file manually due to problem with awstats report.

I am using ISPConfig 3 with the help of the tutorial from [howtoforge](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-ubuntu-12.04-lts-nginx-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3). But due to removing/deleting of some account, the configuration of fstab and mtab messed up.

I also ask this question at howtoforge forum but until now no one has answered. If you'd like to read my question please visit it [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=62378).

I tried very hard to fix the problem w/o luck.

Update:

Here's what happen to my fstab:

Before the value was (I omitted the other):

```
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/mydomain.com /var/www/clients/client1/web1/log    none    bind,nobootwait    0 0
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/example.com /var/www/clients/client1/web2/log    none    bind,nobootwait    0 0
```

So I changed it to the correct path:

```
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/mydomain.com /var/www/clients/client1/web2/log    none    bind,nobootwait    0 0
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/example.com /var/www/clients/client1/web3/log    none    bind,nobootwait    0 0
```

I also found mtab to have the same value as above that's why I edited it manually.

from:

```
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/mydomain.com /var/www/clients/client1/web1/log none rw,bind 0 0
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/example.com /var/www/clients/client1/web2/log none rw,bind 0 0
```

to:

```
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/mydomain.com /var/www/clients/client1/web2/log none rw,bind 0 0
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/example.com /var/www/clients/client1/web3/log none rw,bind 0 0
```

I edited those value because the correct path of mydomain.com and example.com should be under web2 and web3 folder respectively.

As of now the log of example.com is pointed to:

```
/var/www/clients/client1/web2/log
```

when it should be:

```
/var/www/clients/client1/web3/log
```

So I am thinking that this is because of fstab and mtab.

Please guide me how to point the log correctly to it's default directory.

I explain the scenario one by one at this [link](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?p=299156).

Answer (score 60):

File `/etc/mtab` is maintained by the operating system. Don't edit it.

File `/etc/fstab` defines what should be mounted. It is read at system start.

When I add an extra disk to a system that should be mounted at system start
I add it to `/etc/fstab`.

To check the correctness of the updated `/etc/fstab`
I use the command `mount -a`. That reads `/etc/fstab` as system start,
it mounts filesytems that aren'nt yet mounted.

It gives an error when the mountpoint is missing or the device is missing.

To answer the question on rebooting: No, there is no need to reboot after editing `/etc/fstab`.
You can testdrive with `mount -a`

Comment: Usually the problem is that `mount -a` won't remount filesystems that're already mounted. Instead one would rather use `mount <mount-point> -o remount`, like `sudo mount / -o remount`. It will use the options defined in the fstab.

Comment: @Geert Stappers, I modified /etc/fstab on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 today and it almost crashed my system. In other words, It keeps asking for emergency reboot. Thank you

Comment: This didn't work for me on 16.04 guest in VMWare Fusion. I had to extend my primary partition which meant I had to remove the existing swap partition to make room. I edited fstab with the new partition info, but `mount -a` did not make the system recognize the new swap partition. Rebooting did work though.

Comment: FYI: manpage of `mount` states that it is a bad practice to use `mount -a` for checking `/etc/fstab` after editing. To quote: `Note that it is a bad practice to use mount -a for fstab checking. The recommended solution is findmnt --verify.`.

Answer (score 14):

You don't edit `/etc/mtab` manually.

You can, though, change your `/etc/fstab` to add or remove *persistent* mount points, i.e. the ones that will be mounted on startup. Also, the `/etc/fstab` file is used by the `mount(8)` command to refer to mount points.

You can safely define new mount points, or delete existing ones in `/etc/fstab` without altering the current state of the OS. You can manually `mount(8)` and `umount(8)` filesystems that reflect those changes; and you can also remount already mounted filesystems with dfferent options, e.g.:

```
mount -o remount,noexec /var
```

The question here is, why do you think you need `bind` mount points at all and what do you think you are going to achieve by using them? But I disgress.

When dealing with `bind` mount points, the steps to reconfigure your filesystems layout without restarting should be:

1. **Don't edit `/etc/mtab` manually**
2. stop the applications and services that use the filesystems you are going to modify. This is not always possible, but your use case seems to involve only filesystems dedicated to host log files under `/var`.
3. `umount` all `bind` mount points.
4. rewrite `/etc/fstab` to match your needs.
5. manually mount the filesystems.

Comment: Hi, I update my post above. Please read the scenario.

Comment: Actually I don't know why there is a bind mount points. I'm using the tutorial from [link](http://bit.ly/JVth4Y) and I did not add it myself...

Comment: One way to avoid stopping and starting individual services (which could be a chore), is to pass in single user mode (`telinit S`), do the edits, and move back to multiuser(`telinit 2`).

Answer (score 0):

mtab lists currently mounted filesystems, so it is written by the system and its content will change after, say, a reboot, an umount or a new mount. fstab lists available filesystems and is persistent, i.e. it will survive a reboot.

You should not edit mtab directly.